# Stuck on Blood Bowl 2 campaign at 40%

Tags: blood-bowl-2

So, it's pretty simple - I'm playing through the campaign and have got to the match against the Gouged Eye. It says **next match objectives: level up your players**.

The play match button is greyed out though none of my players have enough SPP to advance.

Is this a bug? How do I continue?

Comment: If you like the game in terms of gameplay and tactical complexity, but get tired of this buggy version of it you can try playing on fumbbl.com.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug to me, indeed.
Did you try loading a save and replaying [part of] the match so that one of your players can level up ?
If you don't have a previous save, well... keep one next time :p

I did only play the first version of official blood bowl (Botocs ftw !), but from what I remember, such bugs wouldn't surprise me much.

Are you sure you don't have another problem ? (e.g., needing to hire some temporary player to replace a wounded one ?) I'm not sure such a blocking condition exists, but it can be worth double checking.

Comment: The answer space is for answering the question, not asking more questions.

Comment: There are no saves, it's all online and it auto saves when you finish a match etc.

Comment: @Tim B Indeed, you're screwed then :( Report the bug to officials support if it hasn't been already. Btw, you are not alone [http://steamcommunity.com/app/236690/discussions/0/523898291490459384/](http://steamcommunity.com/app/236690/discussions/0/523898291490459384/)
If you don't want to wait for an hypothetic bugfix and choose to restart the campaign instead, I'd advise to keep as much players as possible close to a level next time you get here.  And choose the good one(s) to score TD, btw :)  Some passes can also help to get a sixth XP, e.g. on players with MVP

Answer (score 1):

If you are technical then get [SQLLite DB Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). Then use it to open campaign.db file in your BloodBowl 2 directory - probably in your user documents. Find the table called bb_player_listing. Find one of your players and increment the value nbLevelsUp to 1. Then write changes and load the game. This will let you give this player a level boost and get past the issue.

Comment: i know this is a very old comment but i just stumbled upon it. wouldn't changing the values in this way mess up the game as it seems to be communicating with a server every time one navigates to the team roster page?